# Thymeleaf is not recognised in Spring Boot 2.0.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I 've been having this weird error in pom.xml

[image: pom.xml]

I don't understand why can't I read the localhost:8080 url. It's very weird.

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping({"","/","index"})
   public String getIndexPage(){
    return "index";
   }
}
```

And my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Recipes Page</title>
<h1>Recipes Index Page</h1>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: This could be a corrupted jar download. `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` or navigate to `.m2/repo/org/springframework/boot/` and delete the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` folder

Comment: please show POM.xml as code and not as picture.

Comment: It's. Everything is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency inside POM.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Please have a look on the following application:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/